# How to find specific entry in Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am beginner android developer( about 2 months of learning =D)
I am writing app, witch write entries of calls from CallLog (Incoming,Outgoing,Missed) to the Google Calendar with some information like Name,Number,Duration,..Now i need to prevent from duplicate entries(Based on content).I tried it this way: Save the date of last written call and then continue from this date, but it is needless resource-consuming, so i want to do it this way: take the date of call and look at the Google calendar, if there is already same entry with same date (same content). And there is finally my problem:I dont know how can i look to the Google calendar (by date), if there is same entry.
In other words how can i find(read) some event by the date?Can someone give me simple example?
Thank you and sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate a user's Google Calendar, please use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).